# How to get value of string which has list of arrays from json object

Tags: javascript, json, string

I have this json

```
var json = { 
    "I:5.3": {
        "conf": {
            "name": "Jack" 
        }
    }
}
```

and this string

```
var str = '["I.5.3"]["conf"]'
```

How can get str value from json like

```
json["I.5.3"]["conf"]
```

I have json object and str and I have to extract something like

```
json[str] = json["I.5.3"]["conf"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your title suggests you would like to get:

- The value of a string.

  - Which has a list of Array's.
- From a JSON object.

However, all your code shows is a Plain JavaScript object.  No arrays to be seen... and the only string value I can find is "Jack".

Jack would be extracted like, `json["I.5.3"]["conf"]["name"]`.
Or via dot notation => 

`const obj = json["I.5.3"];
const nameValue = obj.conf.name; // => Jack`

Answer (score 0):

You would have to split the string up into separate parts, I believe.

```
var str = '["I.5.3"]["conf"]';
var identifiers = str.split('][');
// identifiers would be an array like:
// ["I.5.3", "conf"]

var person = json[identifiers[0]][identifiers[1]];
// person = {
//   "name": "Jack"
// }
```

[String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) allows you to separate parts of a string out into an array. Checkout the MDN docs to learn more about that particular method.

This specific answer expects that there will *always* be the properties you split, though and will error out if one is missing. For something a little safer, I would suggest checking to see if that object contains the property you're expecting before trying to access it.

```
var str = '["I.5.3"]["conf"]';
var identifiers = str.split('][');

try {
  var myVal;
  // Let's check if the property exists.
  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(json, identifiers[0]){
    myVal = json[identifiers[0]];

    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(myVal, identifiers[1]){
      myVal = myVal[identifiers[1]];
    }
  }
} catch(error) {
  // One of the properties didn't exist or something went wrong in the try
  // block above.
}
```

**EDIT:**
The follow would format your string specifically to meet the match to become an array. If there were single quotes or double quotes anywhere in each array item, this would fall through, so be aware of that.

```
var myArray = str.slice(2, -2).split('][').map(function(item) {
  return item.replace('"', '');
});
```

[String.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) extracts a section of a string and returns it as a new string, without modifying the original string.

Then the split method separates it into different array items. Then we iterate over each item in the array and remove additional `"`. Just to say again, this will fall apart if the original string looks like `['one']['two']`. This would also not be reliable if the string looks like `["can't"]["won't"]`. So just be aware of that in your particular case. If you're positive that the string will always meet the format you have above, then you can rely on this.

Comment: **identifiers would be an array like `["I.5.3", "conf"]`**. No, it return `["["I:5.3"", ""conf"]"]`

Comment: Ah, yes. That's because of the first and last square brackets. You'll need to remove those characters from the string before running split on it.

Comment: Added an update to include that. If you're not sure the string will always match the format, I would suggest using a regular expression to replace the specific instances of extra character you don't want. @Mohammad

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways(at least that's what's in coming through my mind now):

**1st way**

```js
var json = { 
    "I:5.3": {
        "conf": {
            "name": "Jack" 
        }
    }
}
var str = '["I:5.3"]["conf"]'
var scr_line = 'json'+str;
var target = eval(scr_line);

console.log(target);
```

**2nd way:**

```js
var json = { 
    "I:5.3": {
        "conf": {
            "name": "Jack" 
        }
    }
}
var str = '["I:5.3"]["conf"]';
let ret = getVal(json, str);
console.log(ret);

function getVal(obj, path){
  var regex = /\["(.*?)"\]/mg;
  let m;

  while ((m = regex.exec(path)) !== null) {
      // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
      if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
          regex.lastIndex++;
      }
      
      if(typeof obj[m[1]] !== 'undefined') obj = obj[m[1]];
      else return obj[m[1]];
  }
  return obj;
}
```

I would prefer the second because it checks if the property on the object exists